# Closing a modal instance causes router to route to default state

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using a urlRouterProvider for a default route on initial page loadup.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/state1/welcome');
```

I have 2 state that loads different HTML pages. On the second state, I have a button that opens a modal and on the modal a cancel button that closes the modal.

```
$scope.modalInstance.dismiss("Cancel");
```

For some reason, calling this method will change my state from /state2/welcome to /start/welcome (The default). Why is it doing this and how do I prevent it from changing my state? I still need to keep the urlRouterProvider, but commenting that out seems to keep the state the same after closing the modal.

Comment: Are you using $uibModal to open the modal?  Are you closing the modal from the same controller that opened it or from the modal's controller?

Comment: I use uibModal to open, I use the same controller and pass in the same scope to close it.